# Check line existence in laravel's trans()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, translation

Lets say in my `lang/en/general.php` there are multiple translation lines for example:

```
"token" => "This password reset token is invalid.",

"sent" => "Password reminder sent!",

"reset" => "Password has been reset!",
```

But in my `lang/de/general.php` these lines are missing.

So later, when I use the `Lang::get('general.token')` or simply `trans('general.token')`

The english version will return

> This password reset token is invalid.

And the german (de) version will return

> general.token

Is there any way I can handle a 'translation not found' function, like a filter but not creating a special class for it? For example, when a line has no translation, I want to throw an Exception.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**In Laravel 4 only**, you can use `Lang::has()` as below, here is [the doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization#basic-usage)

```
if (\Lang::has('general.token')) {

    // line exists.

} else {

   // line not exist.

}
```

Comment: But how do you pass the array in there that holds all translations from the general file?

Answer (score 14):

In current Laravel versions you can just use `trans` helper like so:

```
@if (trans()->has('general.token'))
   {{ trans('general.token') }}
@endif
```

Comment: There's also `trans()->hasForLocale('general.token')`, `Lang::hasForLocale('general.token')`, or `trans()->has('general.token', null, false)` for those wondering. This will check if the key exists in the current locale ONLY.

`trans()->has('general.token')` will check the key in the current locale and fall back to the fallback locale. Only if both are missing will it return `false`.

Answer (score 7):

This question is getting a little bit old but as per version 5.8 you can simply check as this :

```
array_key_exists('your-word-key', trans('your-file'))
```

or

```
array_key_exists('your-word-key', trans('your-file.array_key'))
```

for nested translations

Answer (score 3):

You might want to write a helper similar to the one below to help with fallbacks:

```
/**
 * Makes translation fall back to specified value if definition does not exist
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @param null|string $fallback
 * @param null|string $locale
 * @param array|null $replace
 *
 * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator|null|string
 */
function trans_fb(string $key, ?string $fallback = null, ?string $locale = null, ?array $replace = [])
{
    if (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::has($key, $locale)) {
        return trans($key, $replace, $locale);
    }

    return $fallback;
}
```

Note: The helper only works on PHP 7.1 (which has support nullable types). Adjust it to your PHP version if it's lower than 7.1.

Comment: I couldn't find where or how to create a helper in Laravel as the documentation is not talking about it. I used this tutorial if anybody has the same issue: https://www.kodementor.com/create-custom-helper-functions-in-laravel-5/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own TranslationServiceProvider and Translator and override the get() method in translator to throw an exception when the parent::get() returns a translation string that is equal to the translation key that was passed in. Both @lang() and trans() functions call the get() method of the translator.

Seems like a whole lot of trouble only to get another reason for a "Whoops! something went wrong!" on your site. You will only get the exception when the translation is encountered.

Another solution: you can use the barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager package, it has a translation service provider that logs missing translation keys and a web interface for managing translations. It will log missing translation keys per locale and let you edit them through a web interface.

It is simple to setup and easy to modify. So you can replace the logging with throwing an exception.

Answer (score -2):

Laravel v10.33.0 now provides functionality to handle missing translation strings. In any service provider's `boot` method, you can call:

```php
Lang::handleMissingKeysUsing(function ($key) {
    // Return the string to display, optionally logging out a message here.
});
```

The closure can accept up to 4 arguments, the first one is the translation key which could not be found. The return value of the closure will define the string to return instead of the key itself.

I note the edge case that to prevent infinite loops, this function will not be triggered by translation calls inside itself.

Further info here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization#handling-missing-translation-strings

Comment: Dean Wunder, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my comment with more detail.